How to import theme/styles only into custom-element/lib (js-file) and not apply it for whole application Angular
I have some Angular application that consist of core-app, which has global CUSTOM corporate styles and theme (not Angular Material).
And many child apps which are used inside core-app like js-files. Lets say Angular child-app built into child.js.
In this child-app I use material theme and styles, which I imported into styles.css:
@import "~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
@import '~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';

But after I build my child.js and use it in core-app these imports do not apply.
Yes, I found some workarounds (use ViewEncapsulation.None and put imports in root component of css file child-app), but these workarounds apply import for whole core-app (global) and destroy custom theme and some styles in it.
So I need find the way to apply these imports only whithin child-app, not for whole core-app
